# What are the working of ASIFormDataRequest and ASINetworkQueue in Iphone

Tags: iphone, asiformdatarequest, asinetworkqueue

```
ASIFormDataRequest *request = [ASIFormDataRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://trade2rise.com/project/dry/windex.php?itfpage=register"]];
    ASINetworkQueue *networkQueue = [[ASINetworkQueue alloc] init];
    [request setPostValue:txt_name.text forKey:@"name"];
    [request setPostValue:txt_con_number.text forKey:@"phone"];
    [request setPostValue:txt_email.text forKey:@"email"];
    [request setPostValue:txt_pwd.text forKey:@"password"];
    [request setPostValue:txt_con_pwd.text forKey:@"password2"];
    [request setDelegate:self];
    [request setDidFinishSelector:@selector(requestFinished:)];
    [request setDidFailSelector:@selector(requestFailed:)];
    [networkQueue addOperation:request];
    [networkQueue go];
```

I am new for the Iphone Please explain about abodve term?

Answer (score 1):

If you known the http post method , you will known the key and value pair at the post form. so the code above just like add relative key and value to the form, the add the queue to post request.

ASIFormDataRequest *request // the url bind request,just form post form

ASINetworkQueue *networkQueue // the work queue to maintain the request in a queue (FIFO)